# make better LinQ queries mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, fiddler, performance-testing

I had a question in my mind, to get the better performance of a linq query , is it better to use the select extension to select just the fields we need, not the whole fields?!!!

I have a table "News" and it has fileds ( id, title, text, regtime,regdate,username,...) which the text field is very long text and it has to have a big size for each row.
so i decided to change this query in the index page which does not show the text of news from this

```
var model=db.News.ToList();
```

to this one

```
var model=db.News.Select(n=>new NewsVM(){ id=r.id, title=r.title, regtime=r.regtime,...});
```

and i fiddler both queries and the Bytes Received was the same

Comment: Is there any text in the `text` fields?

Comment: yes, of course there is. in the index page, shows the the list of news containing id,title,... not the text field, and when you click on a link, it shows the whole news with the text.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but we can't be sure.

Comment: I change the query and add the text field( only inside controller) => the result was the same. then i added the text field inside my view and suddenly the Received bytes increased. So base on my test , the query does not affect Received bytes if only add the big size field inside view.

Comment: but does it affect the performance on sql server???

Comment: Your second last comment isn't clear to me. Anyway, a `new NewsVM` _without_ text property _should_ reduce the payload _and_ the amount of data received from Sql Server. You can check the SQL query.

Comment: i was thinking the same way, and i asked this question because i believed that the query without text field should have less received bytes, but apparently it doesn't have any effect unless you add the text field inside the view. it means if i use the first query in the post and don't use text field inside view, it doesn't have any difference with the query number 2. but at least it must have effect on th sql server. right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler doesn't monitor the data sent from the Sql Server to the webserver.  Fiddler will only show you the size of the HTML that the view generates.

So to answer your question, YES! The performance is much better if you ask only for the fields you need rather than either asking for all of them, or blindly using the select method.  The Sql Server should/may run the query faster.  It may be able to retrieve all the fields you are asking for directly from an index rather than having to actually read each row.  There are many other reasons as well, but they get more technical.

As for the webserver, it too will execute faster since it doesn't have to recieve as much data from the sql server, and it will use less memory (leaving more memory available for caching, etc).

A good analogy would be asking if I ask you for the first word of the first 10 books in your library, would it be faster if you had to copy the entire content of each book to your notebook first, then give me the first word, or if it would be faster if you just wrote down the first word of each book.  Both answers are only 10 words long.

Comment: i was thinking the same way, but i misunderstand fiddler. thanks. your answer is truly correct!